# VB.Net Combo Box Number from Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

So i have a database with 2 rows code,name lets say its like
code / name
1 / john
2 / george

i use this query to bring them in my combo box .

```
strConnection = String.Format("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};",
                                          strServer, strDataBase, strUserName, strPassword)

            Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
            Connection.Open()
            Dim cm As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Codeid [Κωδικός],descr [Περιγραφή] FROM EMBONILO_B.DBO.manufacturer GROUP BY Codeid,descr", Connection)
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                ComboBox.Items.Add(dr(1).ToString)
            End While
            dr.Close()
            Connection.Close()
```

and it show the name john and george. What i want is when you click the combo box and you select a name i want the code to appear on the combo box lets say if its george selected i want number 2 in combo box etc.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no set functions are involved?

Comment: GROUP BY is not in use tbh so nothing to look after.

Comment: Why do you want to display the code in the ComboBox? You can display it easy enough when you fill it initially. You can use the codeid in code but are you sure you actually want to change what is displayed?

Comment: Cuz i want to write at my DB the code id cuz other tables use inner join to get some value from the codeid

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding items to the ComboBox you are only setting the Text property, not the Value property. ComboBox.Items.Add() should have an overload where you can do specify the Value as well when you had items in your While loop, something like `ComboBox.Items.Add(dr(1).ToString(), dr(0).ToString())` or maybe `ComboBox.Items.Add(New ListItem(dr(1).ToString(), dr(0).ToString()))` if you are using ASP.NET WebForms for example. Either way, each list item will have separate Text and Value properties; you want to put the ID in the Value property, and you can subsequently get the selected ID in your code using ComboBox.SelectedValue or similar, depending upon the control you are using for a combobox.

My assumption is you really want to obtain the ID in code to store in a db table, not display it in the UI.

Comment: I have not, I can't tell what kind of ComboBox is being referenced. I have provided a suggestion on how to get the desired result, which I assume is having a numeric value associated with the text that is displayed for each item. If this were ASP.NET webforms, then adding new ListItem objects would be the way to go as in my second example.

Comment: I would add that to your answer. Is the first snipper for WinForms?  In any event the OP wants the codeID to display when in the combobox when the item is selected.

Comment: I added some clarification. I answered assuming the OP was trying to figure out how to include the ID in a combobox for subsequent retrieval rather than actually displaying it, which I believe they later stated in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This all applies to a WinForms application.

Declare a Form level variable to hold the `CodeID` of the currently selected descr in the combobox.

Since `GetDescriptionData` is called from `Form.Load` the values `strServer`, `strDatabase` etc. used in the connection string, must be available at this time. If they are not available until some user input is gathered move the code to a button. `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` are names of fields from the Select statement.

Separate the data access code from the user interface code. Connections and commands need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of that for us.

The form level variable `CurrentCodeID` is set in the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
Private CurrentCodeID As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ComboDataTable = GetDescriptionData()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "descr"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Codeid"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetDescriptionData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strConnection = String.Format("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};",
                                      strServer, strDataBase, strUserName, strPassword)

    Using Connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnection),
            cm As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Codeid,descr FROM EMBONILO_B.DBO.manufacturer;", Connection)
        Connection.Open()
        dt.Load(cm.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    CurrentCodeID = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
End Sub
```